# re-enable IE location permissions

Tags: lumia

By accident I blocked google maps from using location on my lumia 520 in IE.  How can I re-enable it?

I looked in the IE settings, and location settings but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried "Settings -> Application Settings -> Internet Explorer -> Delete History" ?  That will delete cookies etc and will most likely result in the next visit to Google Maps asking for permission to provide the location.

Comment: @MaxVernon could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @row - done!  Is that answer format ok, or should I add a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open "Settings -> Application Settings -> Internet Explorer" and click "Delete History".

That will delete cookies etc and will most likely result in the next visit to Google Maps asking for permission to provide the location.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Settings => Application Settings -> Internet Explorer I see an "Advanced settings" button. Under that button there is a toggle to "Allow access to my location".